# Change swig path in CentOS

Tags: centos, path

I have remote account of a super computer. I have to install a software `CMUSphinx`, Which requires `swig 2.0+` version as dependency. But Server have `version 1.3.40` installed.

Now I can not update it because I am not root user,  so I installed `swig 3.0.12` in my local account under the path **$HOME/local/swig** It was installed properly.

But after installation I checked the version and it still says 1.3.40.

So I suppose there must be some path or anything which I need to update but I dont know what exactly I need to change. As I am new to Unix.

[image]

Comment: In the the answers and comments to [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360368/installing-software-without-root-user-access) it was already written that you need to update your `PATH` variable. Better read that or your next problem will be with shared library versions, because you didn't set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @Philippos that was updated later. but still I think that is not what I am looking for. That answer focus on setting user sessions but I want to add path and dont know where to and how to add.

Answer (score 2):

When you type `swig` on the command line, the shell will search for that command in the directories listed in the `$PATH` variable. It will use the *first* match that it finds.

Since the `swig` that you installed (most likely) lives in `$HOME/local/swig/bin` and since this directory is either not in your `$PATH` or too late in the it, it picks up the older version of the command.

Put `$HOME/local/swig/bin` early in your path (verify that this is the correct directory first):

```
PATH="$HOME/local/swig/bin:$PATH"
```

See also [How do I set a user environment variable? (permanently, not session)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session)

Alternatively, run `swig` with the path specified:

```
$ ~/local/swig/bin/swig
```

Or, if you are in your home directory:

```
$ local/swig/bin/swig
```

Comment: i dont know where to add path. can you please tell me that.

Comment: @AdnanAli In your `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bashrc`), add `export PATH="$HOME/local/swig/bin:$PATH"`. Log out and then log in again.