# What is the user equivalent of the global /opt directory?

Tags: home, fhs, xdg, xdg-user-dirs

I'm wondering if anybody has agreed on a user equivalent of the global `/opt` directory, for third-party packages that are distributed as a tarball to be unpacked as a single directory. Examples include Firefox Beta, Tor Browser, and innumerable others.

In the past I've left them wherever I unpacked them, either in my home, in `~/Downloads`, or in other random places, but now I'd like to sort the mess.

I'm thinking either `~/.local/opt` or `~/.opt`, but I'm wondering if there is any standard place that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 6):

There is no standard location for software installed by a non-root user.

A common location include using `$HOME/local` or `$HOME/opt` (with `bin`, `lib` etc. subdirectories).  Some software seems to use `$HOME/.local` by default (the Python `pip` tool and others), which may mean that using that hidden directory might be a less good choice as installing into it may overwrite existing files not managed directly by you.

Another alternative (especially if you compile from sources) is to use [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) and install with e.g. `$HOME/local/stow/package_dir-version` as the installation prefix (rather than `$HOME/local`).  GNU Stow would then populate the hierarchy above the `stow` directory with symbolic links pointing into the various directories under the `stow` directory.

See the question "[How to correctly deal with locally built binaries?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337622/how-to-correctly-deal-with-locally-built-binaries)" for more information.